# Is there alternative to OracleDbType.Array in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

Tags: .net, oracle, standards

I am converting .net framework targeted project to netstandard 2.0. So I changed Oracle.DataAccess to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core. But some oracle db types in OracleDbType enum are not exist in managed driver:

```
OracleDbType.Array
OracleDbType.Object
OracleDbType.Ref
```

Why these types not exist in ODP.NET Managed Driver?
Is there any alternative ways for these types?

Example code is like below. It is used for logging in some certain situations.

```
else if (param.OracleDbType == OracleDbType.Array)
    sbParameters.Append(string.Format("<{0}:{1}>",param.ParameterName, "OracleDbType.Array"));
```

Error : 'OracleDbType' does not contain a definition for 'Array'